# $\|f+g'\|_{L^2}=\|f'-g\|_{L^2}=0\Rightarrow f=g=0$ a.e?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ and $f,g\in H^1(a,b)$. So, $f,f',g,g'\in L^2(a,b)$. Suppose

$$\int_a^b|f+g'|^2\mathrm dx=\int_a^b|f'-g|^2\mathrm dx=0.$$

Is it possible to conclude that $f=g=0$ a.e? If not, could you give me a counter example?

Thanks.

Comment: well $g$ only needs to be $0$ almost everywhere for this to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f(t)=\sin t$, $g(t)=\cos t$.

Comment: Good counterexample, +1.